# Windows not booting after boot-repair

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows

My laptop had Ubuntu pre-installed in it. I installed Windows 7 from USB by following the steps from [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Windows booted fine before I ran boot-repair. However, after I installed and ran the boot-repair from the Ubuntu live CD, Windows has stopped booting. Just a blank screen appears and nothing happens. What to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer, but because that's too much for putting it into a comment.
You can read more on all of these popular threads.

- [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)
- [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)
- [Installing Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Windows 8.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399441/installing-ubuntu-13-10-alongside-windows-8-1)
- [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows)
- [Why don't I have the option ''Install Ubuntu alongside with them''](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69481/why-dont-i-have-the-option-install-ubuntu-alongside-with-them)
- [Ubuntu install and dual Boot with Windows 8 UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193103/ubuntu-install-and-dual-boot-with-windows-8-uefi)
- [Ubuntu 13.10 installer/live fails to boot from DVD/USB on UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/385159/ubuntu-13-10-installer-live-fails-to-boot-from-dvd-usb-on-uefi)
- [Install Ubuntu next to Windows 8 (UEFI dual boot)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236787/install-ubuntu-next-to-windows-8-uefi-dual-boot)
- [Windows 8 removes Grub as default boot manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235567/windows-8-removes-grub-as-default-boot-manager)
- [Windows 8 deletes GRUB when booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/447201/windows-8-deletes-grub-when-booting)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, I'm not installing Ubuntu on pre-installed Windows, I'm doing the other way round. Plus, It's WIndows 7 so it doesn't have the UEFI issues :-)

Comment: No worries. I guess at least three from the list for your case nevertheless: `How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?`,`Windows 8 removes Grub as default boot manager`, `Windows 8 deletes GRUB when booting`

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, and that should solve your issues as long as you don't mind wiping your disk or having the trouble of backing up / moving files around between systems.

Best choice would be to wipe your disk, install Windows first using the first partition and then Ubuntu alongside it.

Comment: ha! That is a very expensive option for me ;-)
Anyways, I don't know how, but Windows starts properly on every second reboot. I'll try to deduce the trick behind this magic!